# What's cause of below Maven exception occuring in Jenkins Build?

Tags: maven, jenkins

What's cause of below Maven exception occuring in Jenkins Build?

It was working initially for versio 3.0.2 - someone accidentally replaced 3.2.3 - we started seeing this error.

3.0.2 was reinstated 
Used commands mvn -U clean install

Doesnt seem to work.. any pointers appreciated.

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.6.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.6.1.pom
Mar 25, 2015 3:17:44 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
Mar 25, 2015 3:17:44 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request
Mar 25, 2015 3:17:44 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
Mar 25, 2015 3:17:44 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request
Mar 25, 2015 3:17:44 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
Mar 25, 2015 3:17:44 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.526 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-25T15:17:44-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/11M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.6.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.6.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
SOE Failed. ( goto :FailResult )
Checking whether SOE.war is built successfully and available.
"Building BatchFeed in Dev Environment...."

 The Command: D:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin\mvn.bat -U clean install

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building feed 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.12.4/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4.pom
Mar 25, 2015 3:17:48 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
Mar 25, 2015 3:17:48 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request
Mar 25, 2015 3:17:48 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
Mar 25, 2015 3:17:48 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request
Mar 25, 2015 3:17:48 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
Mar 25, 2015 3:17:48 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.034 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-25T15:17:48-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/11M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.12.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: Do you use a proxy or something? What is configured in your settings.xml?  Also I would suggest to use the stable version of the 3.0 release 3.0.5 and not the unstable 3.0.2 .. or even better upgrade to the latest 3.2.5 or 3.3.1

Comment: Well we once experienced this when running witht the "wrong" JDK on a Websphere: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21584437 but that wouldnt be triggered by simply changing the Maven version i guess..

Comment: @ManfredMoser settings.xml is empty, we tried switching JDK and tried adding jsse.jar into the IBM JDK - didnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

The error message looks like a network problem (proxy/firewall) whatever as Manfred already mentioned. May be you have wrongly configured your repositories (settings.xml) (you don't seemed to be using a repository manager).

> could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.6.1: Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.6.1 from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find the specified class
>   com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory -> [Help 1]

I can also recommend to upgrade to at least 3.0.5 to be on a stable version better to higher versions.

Comment: @kharbaise we tried changing to Maven 3.2.3 - didnt seem to work

Comment: I have suggested to check network etc. problems first and afterwards to update to newer Maven versions.

Comment: We did, couldn't find any network issues on Jenkins windows server running the maven command..

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what other says about network issue which could be the problem here.

I see I/O exception here.

INFO: I/O exception

Please check your disk as well if it is full or having some problem or permission issue.

Comment: we are not very positive about network issue - since we can download other jars..